# Creating msi or exe installer using setupbuilder plugin in gradle for .net project

Tags: .net, gradle, msbuild, wix

I have a .net project which I build using the MSBuild plugin for gradle. In the final task I want to create a .msi or .exe installer including the dll's from build step. The current gradle build script looks as follows:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.ullink.gradle:gradle-msbuild-plugin:2.16"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.de.inetsoftware:SetupBuilder:1.8.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'msbuild'
apply plugin: "de.inetsoftware.setupbuilder"

msbuild {
// Project solution file
    solutionFile = 'Test.sln'

    targets = ['Clean', 'Rebuild']
}

setupBuilder {
    vendor = 'MyOrg'
    application = "Test"
    appIdentifier = "Test"
    version = '1.0'
    licenseFile = 'license.txt'
    // icons in different sizes for different usage. you can also use a single *.ico or *.icns file
    icons = 'test.icns'
    // all files for all platforms
    from( 'testbuild' ) {
        include 'bin/Debug/*.dll'
    }
    bundleJre = 1.8
}

msi {
    // files only for the Windows platform

}
```

When I run gradle msi, the error is -

```
Execution failed for task ':msi'.
> org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.<init>(Lorg/gradle/internal/reflect/Instantiator;Lorg/gradle/internal/nativeintegration/filesystem/FileSystem;)V
```

I am using gradle 4.2.1 , wixtools, setupbuilder 1.8. Is there any dependency that I'm missing or something in the code block?

Answer (score 0):

According to plugin [reference](https://github.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder) on `GitHub`, `Setup Builder` plugin version `1.8` requires `Gradle` version `3.0`. When I try the `Setup Builder` plugin version 1.8 with the version of `Gradle` is greater than 3.0, similar problems emerged (`WiX Toolset` version is `3.11`). You can try again with `Gradle 3.0`.